# Compare two dates using timestamp in oracle

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, hibernate

```
select * 
  from  table1 rcd, 
        table2 company 
 WHERE to_timestamp(to_char(rcd.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >
       to_timestamp(to_char(company.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

I want to compare two of my date fields using the timestamp (`to_timestamp`) in oracle and I am using above query its not giving correct results (giving records which are not greater than from company.date).

any idea how to compare using the `to_timestamp` in oracle.

Comment: You don't appear to have joined `table1` to `table2`, so you'll get a cartesian product. Is this what you meant?

Comment: `>` can compare time stamps, but you try to select from cartesian producted result set.

Comment: What happens when you just use `rcd.date > company.date`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it works when we direct compare them. but when we use timestamp i think it should also do the same considering the time along with date.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`to_char(<date>)` does not produce the format you are using for `to_timestamp()`.  The safest way would be to repeat the format argument:

```
WHERE to_timestamp(to_char(rcd.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') >
      to_timestamp(to_char(company.date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')
```

Wait.  The safest is to forego all these conversions, and just do:

```
select * 
from table1 rcd join
     table2 company 
     on rcd.date > company.date;
```

Comment: Thks, it's useful

Comment: `rcd.date > to_timestamp(to_char('2018-07-30 17:10:46', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:MI:SS')` is throwing me error `ORA-01722: invalid number`. Any idea why?

Comment: Even this one is also throwing the same error... `rcd.date > to_timestamp(to_char('2018-07-30 17:10:46', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS')`